# Is this SQL an atomic operation for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is this SQL an atomic operation for MySQL ?

```
UPDATE
    api_report a
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            id
        FROM
            api_report
        WHERE
            api_report.success_nums = 7878
    ) b
        ON a.id = b.id 
SET
    a.success_nums = 4646;
```

Assume that I have 2 threads to execute the upper SQL, the data will be updated by 1 of the 2 thread? or by the both 2 thread concurrently?
I wrote a demo, and it seems the data is updated by only 1 of the 2 thread.

Comment: Better idea: instead of worrying about statement atomicity, use transactions!

Comment: sure. but i still wanna get the answer ...

Comment: Can you share more details? Are you facing any real problem that leads you to this question?

Comment: MySQL, like all RDBMS’s, are [*ACID*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) compliant (the “A” is for “Atomic”), so “yes” - the particular statement is irrelevant.

Comment: @Dai Syntax aside, how do transactions help here? Transactions allow rollback and isolation but do they have atomicity features? (Honest question, I'm not an expert).

Comment: @Bohemian I'm going to disagree there - consider MS SQL Server's `MERGE INTO` statement - which is definitely not atomic in itself - you always need to specify an explicit `HOLDLOCK` (or worse) in order to prevent race-conditions with `MERGE INTO`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Transactions are atomic: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/227563/how-a-transaction-is-atomic (granted, with loads of edge-cases that I won't get into)

Comment: @Dai So, MySQL won't show changes in tables made from other sessions from the moment you run `START TRANSACTION`? That's pretty cool.

Comment: @Dai you can also set read uncommitted true, and various other techniques to subvert ACID. But in the general case queries are atomic.

Answer (score 0):

Use correct multiple-table syntax:

```sql
UPDATE api_report a
  JOIN api_report b ON a.id = b.id
SET a.success_nums = 4646
WHERE b.success_nums = 7878
```

Attention! this query will update ALL matched rows including one which has `success_nums = 7878`. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a107e657110147f0a7b7f12b5e099a32). If you does not need this then add more conditions to WHERE clause, for example, `AND a.success_nums != 7878`.

This SQL seems to be an atomic operation for MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, but I don't understand the relation between the question and your experiment. It is well-known that MySQL counts (and writes) actual updates only, if new value is equal to old one then this update is not counted as actual.